# Minecraft Forge hat is causing this error when I run `./gradlew wrapper`?

Tags: java, gradle, daemon, gradlew, minecraft-forge

I'm having quite a bit of trouble with `./gradlew`. I am trying to make a 1.14.4 mod, and have been having a lot of problems with `gradle`, but I've finally got `gradle` working (an error in my `build.gradle` code). I'm on a Mac, and my friend (with whom I am building the mod) is not, and running

```
./gradle wrapper
```

works fine on his computer but not on mine. It must be a system issue, but I'm really not sure. The error I keep getting is:

```
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
```

I've looked online, and all of the work-arounds I have found doesn't help me. Running `./gradlew wrapper` with `--info` I get [this](https://pastebin.com/b9C2c84U). Running with `--stacktrace`, I get [this](https://pastebin.com/nMNaG2dW). Finally, with `--debug` I get [this](https://pastebin.com/0LsAhtge). I don't know if these are helpful (I'm sure they are, if you know what to look for).

Any insights into what on earth is causing this is greatly appreciated!

P.S.: my made-up username in the pastebin links is `drdeducer` :)

P.P.S.: it isn't just `./gradlew wrapper` that doesn't work; it is `./gradlew <anything>`—even just `./gradlew`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem for me.  In the process of trying to initially get gradle working, I added `touch ~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and specified `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home`.  Typing `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` you will get a list of your Java versions, so in my local `gradle.properties`, I had to specify a Java version less than 11 (it ended up being open `adoptopenjdk-8.jdk`).  To see Java versions, type `brew search java`, and then `brew cask install <desired java version>` (for mac users).